# Positioned in a way that is ready to intercept?

Tags: synonyms, sports

If you were to anticipate something, perhaps an opponents serve in a racket sport like tennis, what would you call such anticipation? It's an interception of course, but what else can it be called?

Comment: How is it an "interception?" How is an interception a position?

Comment: Well, it's a *prediction*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *get the jump on*?

Cambridge:

> [*get the jump on*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-a-jump-on-sb-sth): to start doing something before other people start, or before
>   something happens, in order to win an advantage for yourself

Very common in American sports, e.g., football, when a defensive player *gets the jump on* an offensive player and *intercepts* a forward pass.